# Will Bubble Messaging in System Tray Work in Metro?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, bubble-popup

There is an application that I'm using at the minute which uses the system tray for bubble messaging i.e. informing the users of useful information regarding their application.

If this was to be triggered while a user was in 'Metro' mode, would this still appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a notification mechanism for metro style applications built into Windows 8, but it does NOT use the ShNotifyIcon API (which is used for balloon notifications in Windows 7).  Check out the [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.aspx) runtime class for more information.